# $_SESSION['table'] being overwritten by POST method var

Tags: php

Why is my $_SESSION['table'] being overwritten every time I use POST method? Whenever I get a new $mark variable from $POST method $_SESSION ['table'], its being placed on the place of the older one.

```
<?php
session_start();

    if (!isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
        setcookie('name', serialize($_SESSION['table']), time() + 3600 * 24);
        echo('Cookie has been made');
    }

    if (isset($_SESSION['counter'])) {
        $counter = $_SESSION['counter'];
        $_SESSION['counter'] = $_SESSION['counter'] + 1;
    }

    $_SESSION['table'] = [];

    var_dump($_SESSION['table']);

    if ('POST' === $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {

        $mark = isset($_POST['mark']) ? trim($_POST['mark']) : NULL;
    }


    $_SESSION['table'][] = $mark;
    $_SESSION['table'][] = 3;


    var_dump($_SESSION['table']);



     function calcArithmeticMark() {
       $sum = 0;
           foreach ($_SESSION['table'] as $value) {
        $sum += $value;
              }
            $result = $sum / count($_SESSION['table']);

            return $result;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: BTW, you can use `$result = array_sum($_SESSION['table'])/count($_SESSION['table'])` instead of looping over the array yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script empties the session variable every time with:

```
$_SESSION['table'] = [];
```

You should only do that if the variable is not set and needs to be initialized:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['table'])) {
    $_SESSION['table'] = [];
}
```

Comment: @Slay33 Not 'dumb': literally *every* programmer has made this mistake. Please be courteous and accept this by checking the green check mark beside Barmar's answer.